# Validate additional data in contract code or not?

Tags: solidity, web3js, gas, web3.py

Is it better and more friendly in terms of gas and other resources to perform transaction data validation using web3 externally or to perform it in smart contract?

Comment: Could you give an example of the kind of validation?

Answer (score 3):

You should do it both client-side and inside the smart contract.
Validating data inside the smart contract will prevent users from sending malicious data.

Validating client-side will prevent the user from submitting data that will fail and help you give them real-time feedback when dealing with transactions (writing data) since, if it fails, the gas used will be lost, for example.

Comment: Absolutely. A smart contract needs to validate enough to ensure the internal integrity of the application at all times, with no assumptions about the friendly intent of the client. A user-friendly client should be validating data before it tries to send transactions to the contract.